# Javascript: How can i display a pop up box in the canvas when timer ends?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-development

i am very new to javascript and i have been stuck with this issue for a while, where i want to display a pop up box with a message "Game Over, you ran out of time" so the player knows the game is finished.The game is simple, when the game starts a countdown will commence and the user has to answer as many questions correctly within the time limit, for each correct answer, a red ball will travel upwards and the score will increment.The seconds and run-timer function, is in example i modified it a bit, but now i am lost as i really don't know to go about it, i want to modify it further so when the timer reaches 0:00 a window should pop up.Here is my full code so far.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let x = 450,
  y = 350;
let count = 0;

window.onload = function() {
  let btn = document.getElementById("submitAnswers");
  btn.onclick = jump;
};


document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 01 + ":" + 11;

function checkSecond(sec) {
  if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {
    sec = "0" + sec
  };
  if (sec < 0) {
    sec = "59"
  };
  return sec;
}

function runTimer() {
  const presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
  const timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
  let m = timeArray[0],
    s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
  if (s == 59) {
    m -= 1
  }
  if (m < 0) {
    return
  }

  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;



}
setInterval(runTimer, 1000);


function submitAnswers() {
  const answer1 = document.querySelector("#Q1").value
  if (answer1 == 40) jump();

  const answer2 = document.querySelector("#Q2").value
  if (answer2 == 25) jump();
}

function jump() {
  count += 1;
  //changing the y position
  y -= 6;
}

function draw() {
  //clearing the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);

  //redrawing the circle   
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fill();

  //drawing the count value
  context.font = '25px Arial';
  context.fillStyle = 'white';

  context.fillText("Count: " + count, 20, 30);

  context.font = '25px Arial';
  context.fillStyle = 'white';
  let theTime = document.getElementById('timer').textContent;
  context.fillText("Timer: " + theTime, 200, 30);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<h1 align="center"></h1>my jumper game </h1>
<p align="center"> </p>A Fun flappy-bird like game</p>


<div>
  <p>What is 10 times 4 ? <input type="number" id="Q1"></p>
  <p>What is 5 * 5 ? <input type="number" id="Q2"></p>
  <p>What is 5 * 3 ? <input type="number" id="Q3"></p>
  <button onclick="submitAnswers()" id="submitAnswers">Submit</button>

</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="400">
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      
    </canvas>
<br> </br>


<body onload="startGame()">

  <div>Time left = <span id="timer"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you would need to do is to create a "popup" within the canvas itself.

You can create an object with a white background color, then add a border and text within it. You'd probably also need to add a button to close the "popup".

Use resources like the below articles to help figure it out, but I'm pretty sure you can use HTML elements within the `canvas` tag to help create this modal box. It looks like you already know how to deal with text, so this shouldn't be difficult for you.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_canvas.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas

BTW, canvas objects are just like any other `object` in that you can keep track of them. With `canvas`, if you delete an object is covering another object, it reveals the covered object. This is the difference between raster and vector, where raster would replace the visual data/elements and vector layers the visual information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it very simple you could go with the "[alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert?retiredLocale=de)" method. Place it inside the `runTimer` function:

```
if (m < 0) { 
  alert("You ran out of time!");
  return;
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to add a custom popup from within the canvas - maybe this would be a little overkill for a simple game?